# Using docker environment variables in docker-compose run commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This works:

```
$ docker-compose run web psql -U dbuser -h db something_development
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file has environment variables all over the place.  If I run `docker-compose run web env` I see all kinds of tasty things I'd like to reuse in these one off commands (scripts and one-time shells).

```
docker-compose run env
...
DATABASE_USER=dbuser
DATABASE_HOST=db
DATABASE_NAME=something_development
DB_ENV_POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
... many more
```

This won't work because my current shell evals it.

`docker-compose run web psql -U ${DATABASE_USER} -h ${DATABASE_HOST} ${DATABASE_NAME}`
```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
````

These environment variables are coming from an env file like `.app.env` as referenced by docker-compose.yml but docker-compose itself can set environment variables.  Seems a shame to even type `dbuser` when they are right there.  I've tried my normal escaping tricks.

```
docker-compose run web psql -U \$\{DATABASE_USER\} -h \$\{DATABASE_HOST\} \$\{DATABASE_NAME\}
... many other attempts
```

I totally rubber ducked on SO so I'm going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 4):

The answer (and there may be many ways to do it) is to run bash with `-c` and use single quotes so that your local shell doesn't interpolate the string.

`docker-compose run web bash -c 'psql -U ${DATABASE_USER} \
  -h ${DATABASE_HOST} ${DATABASE_NAME}'`

Fantastic.  DRY shell commands in docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

prob not the answer you want but the way we set env vars ...

(this is one of many containers)

```
api:
  image: 10.20.2.139:5000/investigation-api:${apiTag}
  container_name: "api"
  links:
    - "database"
    - "ldap"
  ports:
    - 8843:8843
  environment:
    KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: "ooooo"
    KEYSTORE: "${MYVAR}"
  volumes_from:
    - certs:rw
```

running compose ...

```
MYVAR=/etc/ssl/certs/keystoke.jks docker-compose (etcetera)
```

typically the above line will be in a provision.sh script - cheers

Comment: That's passing an env from the host machine.  I wanted a way to reused the KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: "ooooo" one.  See my answer but thanks!  :)

Comment: just updated answer - hopefully that works for you :) only used it on one place in my example but could be used in many

Comment: Well this is handy regardless.  That's another flexibility option.  Thanks.